# Returning a reference from a function that searches an STL vector

Tags: c++, stl, reference

If I search a vector for a value using the standard library `find()` function, will the following code return the proper references? If the search finds the desired value in the vector, it should return a reference to that value. If it does not, it should push the value onto the end and return a reference to the new value.

I can't tell. Returning `a.back()` should be fine, because it's a reference by definition. It's dereferencing the iterator in the case where `i` is found that I'm unsure of.

```
 int& foo(int i)
 {
     std::vector<int>::iterator found = find(a.begin(), a.end(), i);
     if (found != a.end())
     {
        return *found;
     } else {
        a.push_back(i);
        return a.back();
     }
 }
```

I can't tell. Returning `a.back()` should be fine, because it's a reference by definition. It's dereferencing the iterator in the case where `i` is found that I'm unsure of. The whole point, as is probably obvious, is to get the function to act as an lvalue. It certainly compiles, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dereferencing an iterator you get a reference. Basically, `a.back()` is equivalent to `*(a.end() - 1)` (for containers with random access iterators). That is, the function looks OK. Note, that references to `std::vector<T>` elements stay valid until the vector is destroyed or elements are relocated, e.g., due to resizing the vector.

Comment: "or elements are relocated, e.g., due to resizing the vector" -- so in particular, if you call `foo` twice then after the second call, the result of the first call might not still be valid. The only thing you could really do to avoid that without changing the meaning of the function is to replace the `vector` with a `deque`.

Comment: I will have to think about the failure cases. In the real code, this is a parentheses operator overload for a sparse matrix class. The reference should just be there long enough for assignment, but then I cannot control what someone else might do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK in both cases.

- Per *§ 24.2.2 / Table 106* : For iterator `r`, expression `*r` returns a reference.
- Per *§ 23.3.6.1* : method `back()` returns a reference.

And you can return them as references too.